# Having a parameter on a report which gets values from an expression

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently building an SSRS Report which will need to be filtered by a Name detailed in a long string. For example by Glenn Bob as below:

cn=glenn bob, ou=infoservs, ou=bht, dc=myplaceofwork, dc=int Glenn Bob 16 December 2015 10:57:45

I have been able to extract the Name by using an expression:

=Mid(Fields!sig_clinician.Value, InStr(Fields!sig_clinician.Value,"=")+1, (InStr(Fields!sig_clinician.Value, ",") - InStr(Fields!sig_clinician.Value, "=") - 1))

I named that Field 'sig_clinician1'.

Is there any way that I can use the result of this expression as a Parameter in my report so that when a User opens the report it can be filtered by the information in that expression?

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Comment: I'd create a dataset to extract that name for every row and use that dataset to populate the parameter. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, many thanks for steering me in the right direction. Would you mind talking me through I could do this, or perhaps point me in the direction of some help guides that might explain this. I've had a search around for what you've said but really not sure if I'm looking at the right stuff. Sorry, I am very new to this. Many thanks again.

Comment: Alejandro, many thanks I've figured out what you meant now. KR Glenn